# "I was going to do,but something happened", "I was to do,but something happened" and "I was about to do,but something happened"have the same meaning?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, construction, future-in-past

Do "**I was going to do**,but something happened", "**I was to do**,but something happened" and "**I was about to do**,but something happened"have the same meaning?.I'm so confused right now.
Please give me some advices and explanations.

Comment: They mean different things to me.  “I was going to do” means “I was planning on doing”,  “I was to do” seems off as an AmE (I could more easily imagine it in BrE) but I’d take it to mean “I was supposed to do” and “I was about to do” means my doing it was mere moments away.

Comment: *I was to do, but something happened* doesn't work for me (BrE speaker). You could make it work by expanding the infinitive e.g. *I was to go to sea, but after my elder brother died my father insisted I take over the family business*. It still sounds very old fashioned. Unless you are reading a very old book you are much much more likely to come across *I was supposed to*. As for the other two constructions, the difference is the same in BrE as Jim has explained.

Comment: Does the explanation in the following post *http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/be-to-verb-are-to-get* relate to these construction I mentioned?